# Get SVG from html for later use

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 svg in index.html

```
<ul>
  <li class="players" id="player1">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="42" height="42" viewBox="0 0 42 42" version="1.1"><g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><g transform="translate(-200.000000, -60.000000)" fill="#000000"><g transform="translate(200.000000, 60.000000)"><path d="M21 36.6L21 36.6C29.6 36.6 36.6 29.6 36.6 21 36.6 12.4 29.6 5.4 21 5.4 12.4 5.4 5.4 12.4 5.4 21 5.4 29.6 12.4 36.6 21 36.6L21 36.6ZM21 42L21 42C9.4 42 0 32.6 0 21 0 9.4 9.4 0 21 0 32.6 0 42 9.4 42 21 42 32.6 32.6 42 21 42L21 42Z"/></g></g></g></svg>

  </li>
  <li class="players" id="player2">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="42" height="43" viewBox="0 0 42 43" version="1.1"><g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><g transform="translate(-718.000000, -60.000000)" fill="#000000"><g transform="translate(739.500000, 81.500000) rotate(-45.000000) translate(-739.500000, -81.500000) translate(712.000000, 54.000000)"><path d="M30 30.1L30 52.5C30 53.6 29.1 54.5 28 54.5L25.5 54.5C24.4 54.5 23.5 53.6 23.5 52.5L23.5 30.1 2 30.1C0.9 30.1 0 29.2 0 28.1L0 25.6C0 24.5 0.9 23.6 2 23.6L23.5 23.6 23.5 2.1C23.5 1 24.4 0.1 25.5 0.1L28 0.1C29.1 0.1 30 1 30 2.1L30 23.6 52.4 23.6C53.5 23.6 54.4 24.5 54.4 25.6L54.4 28.1C54.4 29.2 53.5 30.1 52.4 30.1L30 30.1Z"/></g></g></g></svg>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I get both of them in a useable format so that I can append them into another div later using javascript or jquery?

This is what I have so far.

```
var x = $('#player1 svg');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get elements using class name since both li has common class name.

```
var x = $('.players svg');

// later append using append()
$li1.append(x.eq(0));
$li2.append(x.eq(2));
```

Comment: I made a mistake. To clarify I want to be able to put each svg shape into 2 different li elements.